# Camera protocol doesn't work

Tags: kde, camera, dolphin, kde4

My Android device is set to use the media player mode when the USB cable is plugged in.

When I plug it in, it launches the media player thingy on my device and it shows up in the "Device Notifier" applet.

It shows up in Dolphin as two entries:

> Samsung Galaxy Nexus/Galaxy S i9000, Android 4.0 updates

and the same thing, but without the slash.

Then, when I click on the first one, it says:

> The process for the camera protocol died unexpectedly.

and it just sits there and tries to load.

When I click the second one, it says:

> Unknown error
>   Unknown model

and it just sits there and tries to load.

Is there any way to fix this, or is this just a bug in Kubuntu?

I have a Samsung YP-G1 (stock ROM/kernel, rooted) and am running Precise on my computer.

Comment: No activity. Hmm... Maybe I should report this on Launchpad.

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and deals with EOL Ubuntu 12.04 or another EOL version. VTC as `not reproducible`.

Comment: Honestly, go ahead and close it if you want. I don't have the device anymore anyway.